# What changes to Places API will Google My Business bring if any?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

The app that I am working with now uses Google Places API library. I was wondering what Google My Business will mean for developers? Is it just a different product name or is there some changes that will possibly be made?

And I know this is probably a good question for Google itself, but I wanted to find out if someone from developers would know something.

PS: I did a lot of searching on the topic and could not find anything so far, that's why I am asking here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a programming problem

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/business/befound.html says _"Your verified business information can appear in Maps, helping customers find directions to your business. They can also find contact info, as well as ratings and reviews of your business."_  I don't think you'll find out much more than that